# Display all the items I have ordered

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, joptionpane

How to display all the items I have ordered in "Sales Report File"? Like whenever I ordered 2 cookies, It will display on the Sale Report file. I have this code currently..

```
     private final Dispenser candy = new Dispenser(100, 50);
     private final Dispenser chips = new Dispenser(100, 65);
     private final Dispenser gum = new Dispenser(75, 45);
     private final Dispenser cookies = new Dispenser(100, 85);
     public int products;

     private final JButton candyB;
     private final JButton chipsB;
     private final JButton gumB;
     private final JButton cookiesB;


   private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
   {
     public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
     {
        switch (e.getActionCommand()) 
        {
            case "Exit":
              System.exit(0);
            case "Candy":
                sellProduct(candy, "Candy");
                products++;
                break;
            case "Chips":
                sellProduct(chips, "Chips");
                products++;
                break;
            case "Gum":
                sellProduct(gum, "Gum");
                products++;
                break;
            case "Cookies":
                sellProduct(cookies, "Cookies");
                products++;
            case "Sales Report File":
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Items list sold + "+ DISPLAY ALL THE ITEMS ORDERED  
               ,"Sales Report ~ ",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE)
                break;
     }
   }
```

Comment: Do you want to save your data temporary (they are deleted when the application is closed) or permanently (they are saved even if the application is closed) ?

In the first case, you need to hold your data in a data structure, maybe an Arraylist of objects. And then use this arraylist to generate the report.

In the second case, you need to setup a database and hold your data there. And then query the data to generate the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want like a text list of what you have ordered, you can simply create an `ArrayList<String>` and every time you click on a product you do `list.add('Cookies')` or whatever the product is, depending on the switch. In this way you have a list ordered by time-ordered products.

The output would be something like:

```
Cookies,
Candies,
Candies,
Gum,
Chips,
Gum
...
```